# Unable to see user list in search referenced field iDempiere-7.1

Tags: idempiere

I have a window tab based on a table that has a foreign key reference to `AD_User` via `ad_user_id`.  In Tables and Columns this column is given a `'Search' Reference`  with `AD_User` as the `Reference Key`.

When I open the tab with the `ad_user_id` field the search icon (green arrow) is displayed in the field for the user id but when the lookup is performed only the GardenAdmin logged on user, the one creating the record, is available to select.  There are six users defined for GardenWorld, all of which are active.

What else needs to be done to get all the availible users on the selection list?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting -1 as the default for that new AD_User_ID field.

In iDempiere fields take defaults from different sources:

- the first is the default defined in the column
- if not set then it takes a user preference
- if not set then it takes a global preference

  - this must be the case with your field, any field AD_User_ID will take the default defined in the context with @#AD_User_ID@.  The same happens with AD_Role_ID and other fields that have a preference.
- if global preference is not set then there are a lot of records marked as Default, and those are taken also as a global default

Note the order to get the defaults can be differently managed via the System Configurator key [ZK_SEQ_DEFAULT_VALUE_PANEL](https://wiki.idempiere.org/en/System_Configurator_(Window_ID-50006)#ZK_SEQ_DEFAULT_VALUE_PANEL)